# Is the final step to integrate a feature into a main branch (almost) always git merge?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I'm trying to understand the workflow when using feature branches in Git.

Is the final step in integrating **any** change from a feature branch **always** ultimately a `merge` (the exception being if I want to maintain my own separate branch of a project)?

And is `rebase` an alternative to `merge` in the steps **prior** to the final integration which mainly affects the way the history is preserved?

Comment: a rebase is a merge. and how can you have two heads? you mean two branches?

Comment: A rebase may be a merge, but I am interested in understanding the differences. I meant 'heads'. Doesn't each branch have a head, i.e, a latest commit?

Comment: from my understanding the HEAD points to the latest commit or better to the branch label of that commit, unless you have a detached head which is HEAD poitning to a commit, not the branch label

Comment: in a nutshell a rebase is just moving the base of a branch to the tip of another branch. updating commit ids, applying the commits to the new base (that's where you merge) and overwriting the history.

Comment: I understand what rebase does. It just seems to me that the point about a merge being needed ultimately to get a change into the main branch is very rarely mentioned. Instead, the discussion is usually about what the history will look like. For beginners at least, the point about the history seems to me to be far less important.

Comment: you cannot say you understand what a rebase does and ask if a merge is necessary to do a rebase at the same time.  I cannot follow you. how would you get two branches into one if not through a merge?

Comment: Where did I ask if "a merge is necessary to do a rebase at the same time"?  My point is simply that discussions about the difference between merging and rebasing mainly revolve around the differences in the resulting history.  It seems to me, however, that the main difference is a functional one, namely that of getting a branch "up-to-date" (rebase) or getting changes in a feature branch into the main branch (merge).   I wanted to know whether this impression is correct.

Comment: In my workflow, I work on a branch when I'm implementing some feature. The history might be messy, and there might be change to main that I need to incorporate. To clean up my messy history, I use an interactive rebase. To incorporate changes in main, sometimes I rebase my branch onto main, but sometimes I merge main into my branch. Both options works fine, it just depends on what I think is most suitable each time (I don't have hard rules here, though, it's more of a feel).

Comment: Then, when my feature is ready to incorporate into main, I use a merge into main. That takes my branch's history and incorporates it in main's history. Now, here, there might be two kinds of merge I'll use: if the branch was only one commit, I'll probably fast-forward merge it into main, making sure the commit log gave all the details I wanted the main history to have about the feature. If the branch had a lot of commits, I'll use a non-fast-forward merge so that I can summarize in the merge commit what the feature is at a high level. With two or three commits, I might go either way.

Comment: Finally, there is a third kind of merge that GitHub proposes for PRs: a "rebase merge". But that's not really a new kind, it's just that GitHub will do the rebase onto main for me and then do a fast-forward merge. I use this only for PRs with only a commit or two, again, when I don't feel the need to document in the merge commit what the branch contributes.

Comment: @joanis: Your detailed description of how to use merge and rebase within a workflow is exactly what I feel is missing from most discussions.

Comment: @loris I'm glad I could be of help.

Comment: @loris I just turned my comments into an answer, and fleshed them out a little bit more. I think your question is a useful one for people learning to use Git and feature branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The short answer

When you use feature branches for your development work, yes, you always need to use a merge to bring your work into your main branch, once it's ready.

Rebases can be useful to clean up your feature branches before merging them in.

### More details from my workflow

In my workflow, I almost always work on a branch when I'm implementing some feature or fixing some bug.

##### Working in the branch and cleaning it up

The history in the branch might be messy, and there might be changes to main that I need to incorporate.

To clean up my messy history, I typically use an interactive rebase.

To incorporate changes made by others in main, sometimes I rebase my branch onto main, but sometimes I merge main into my branch. Both options works fine, it just depends on what I think is most suitable each time (I don't have hard rules here, though, it's more of a feel).

##### Different ways of merging into main

Then, when my feature or bug fix is ready to incorporate into main, I merge it into main. That takes my branch's history and incorporates it in main's history.

Now, here, there might be two kinds of merge I'll use: if the branch was only one commit, I'll probably fast-forward merge it into main, making sure the commit log gave all the details I wanted the main history to have about the feature.

If the branch had a lot of commits, I'll use a non-fast-forward merge (i.e., a merge that creates an actual merge commit) so that I can summarize in the merge commit log what the feature is, at a high level. With two or three commits, I might go either way.

Finally, there is a third kind of merge that GitHub proposes for PRs: a "rebase merge". But that's not really a new kind, it's just that GitHub will do the rebase onto main for me and then do a fast-forward merge. I typically use this only for PRs that have just one or two commits, again, when I don't feel the need to document in the merge commit what the branch contributes.